# date_select can't remove year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have a question that might seem simple but I can't figure the solution. I use a date_select in a form and pass a discard_year attribute but in the database the date is stored with year default to 0001. Is there a way that I can have it not store the year at all? I just need the month and day. My code is really simple:

```
<%= f.label :closed_from %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :closed_from, :include_blank => true, :discard_year => true %>
```

Comment: I suspect it's because the datatype in the database is a `DATE` or similar, where storing the year is not optional.

Comment: Yes it is a date. I want it to be a date in order to be able to make comparisons between my stored dates. Is there another way to do it? I mean I am trying to store when a place is closed (e.g from July 1st till July 22nd) and not use it when current date is between these...